# R: Trying to assign to a list passed as an argument

Tags: r

I want to pass the name of a list as an argument to a function, and then assign to that list inside the function. The following illustrates the problem.

```
names <- c("a", "b", "c")
mylist <- list()

foo <- function(listname) {
for(name in names){
    listname[[name]] <<- 7
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, and generates an error that "listname" is not known. Can anyone clear this up, please?  I would be most grateful.

Comment: Presumably you are doing `foo(mylist)`. The problem is almost certainly that `<<-` should be changed to `<-`. Also, it would be better to pass `names` into `foo` as well as `listname`.

Comment: Thank you.  My use of <<- is very deliberate.  After calling foo(mylist) I want to have a list, mylist, with elements mylist$a, b, c, each of which is (in this example) 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got a couple of things going wrong. First off, I don't think you have anything stored in `mylist`, i.e. there are no names or anything there for your function to check. Try setting up your list something like this:

```r
mylist <- list("a", "b", "c")
names(mylist) <- c("a", "b", "c")
mylist
#> $a
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "b"
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] "c"
```

In your function, you need to a) do `names(listname)` so you are checking the names of the actual list and b) return the list after you do the reassignment. Then, it can assign to the list *and* it will return those values.

```r
foo <- function(listname) {
    for(name in names(listname)){
        listname[[name]] <- 7
    }

    listname
}

foo(mylist)
#> $a
#> [1] 7
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 7
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] 7
```

Notice that `mylist` still has the same values in it; nothing there got reassigned.

```r
mylist
#> $a
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "b"
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] "c"
```